# Second scanf for character doesn't work

Tags: c, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void trinanguloNumeros(){
    char caracter = 'y';
    int iTamano;

    while (caracter == 'Y' || caracter == 'y') {
        printf("Realizar triangulo:\n");
        printf("De que tamaño desea su triangulo? [1-20]");
        scanf("%i", &iTamano);

        int i,j;
        for(i=1; i<= iTamano; i++ ){
            for(j=1; j <= i; j++){
                printf("%i", j);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }

        printf("Desea Intentar nuevamente? [y/n]\n");
        scanf("%c", &caracter);
        printf("%c", caracter);

    }
    printf("Termina!!");
}

int main(void){
    trinanguloNumeros();
    return 0;
}
```

The second `scanf` for the var `caracter` doesn't works and breaks the  `while` loop. I have no idea why this breaks the loop and the variable is not set again.

Comment: `Does not works` means throws exception ?

Comment: Put a `space` in front of `%c` this will prevent `scanf` from reading the `newline` left in the buffer by the previous `scanf`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put a `space` in front of `%c` to prevent `scanf` from reading the `newline` left in the buffer by the previous `scanf`.

```
scanf(" %c", &caracter);     // see the added space?
```

This `space` consumes all *whitespace* left in the input buffer. In the case of `%d` and `%s` formats, it happens automactically, but not with the `%c` format.

Comment: Wow. I was not aware a space would handle it, and was generally doing it with an extra `scanf` (which is an alternative, but this is definitely neater). +1

Comment: The `newline` might have been left by a previous `%d` format for `int`, in which case your additional `scanf` would have to precede the `char` entry. But if there wasn't one there, your method would fail.

Comment: Then, after the first ´scanf´, should I put a space before any ´%ANYTHING´ on the next ones?  Which could be a better way to make this?

Comment: Just put one before the `%c` format. As said in the answer, most formats consume leading whitespace anyway. Note to self: read the manual.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `\n` remains in the buffer. You can `fflush(stdin);` but I do not advice you to do that because of undefined behaviour. Instead you can put a space before `%c`, this will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because scanf leaves the new line character in the buffer after reading the first value. Hence the while loop breaks.

```
 scanf("\n%c", &caracter);
```

This should fix your problem.